Using geojson file I want to create a navigation system and find shortest path and draw a line
I have a Geojson file with road network. Now what I want is to create a navigation system using this geojson file. I draw the road network using Leaflet js. now I need help to apply dijgsta algorithm or A* algorithm to find a shortest path and draw a line from locaiton A to location B.
I need some documentation or tutorial for this.
I am using javascript and Leaflet js.
using leflet js I draw the road network. now need to apply algorithm and find shortest path. How can I achive this?
